# Insert DIV without knowing element classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla

I am trying to insert a DIV on several positions in Joomla websites; not only in native articles but also in other components. The positions are:

- After title
- Below article
- Right / left of article

Since every component has its own layout and each template can use its own setup (I think) I cannot use the default JQuery functions append(), after(), etc because the classes to be used as reference can differ for each component / template.

In what way is it possible to make a generic solution that works for all (Joomla) websites?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Roy

Comment: It is possible to select elements without using classes.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Do you know how to select these elements in a generic way (e.g. to insert a div below an article)?

Comment: The question is: how do you find the _article_? Is it a unique HTML element that is used once in a page? Does it have an id? Does one of its parent or previous siblings have an id? Is it always, for example, third child of the body element? Does it have an attribute? If you have sufficient information you can write proper (and not necessarily complicated) CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have found that this is indeed the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can choose to do this runtime instead of dynamically, your best option here is to create a Joomla content plugin, since all your manipulations are related to articles.

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content

onContentAfterTitle for your 1st requirement, onContentPrepare or onContentBeforeDisplay for the 2nd and third.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! I am using a system plugin and these events do not work in that case, but I will use these events in a next plugin.